# Dynamic dropdown list in the jsp

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets, jstl

I have a dropdown list which is dynamic so how can I iterate and insert the list values in the dropdown list?

```
var questionids = {"Name", "Age", "Smoker", "Drinker", "Visit Denist"};

<select name="questionid" id="questionids">
<c:forEach var="questionids" items="${questionids}">
<option value="">${questionids}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
```

I tried as mentioned above. it is not working. Also I need the value of each option should auto increment like, For first option value is 1 and second option value is 2. e.t.c

Can any one please suggest the solution please

Comment: Take a look at this post   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740616/load-the-drop-down-list-dynamically-using-jstl

Answer (score 0):

This is right approach but you have to give another name to `var` in `<c:forEach>` like below:

```
var questionids = {"Name", "Age", "Smoker", "Drinker", "Visit Denist"};

<select name="questionids" id="questionids">
    <c:forEach var="questionid" items="${questionids}">
        <option value="${questionid}">${questionid}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Comment: I tried the same code which you suggested but it is not working

Comment: No errors, but the values are not showing in the dropdown list

Answer (score 0):

```
<% java.util.HashMap map = new java.util.HashMap(); 
map.put("0", "Name"); 
map.put("1", "Age"); 
map.put("2", "Smoker"); 
map.put("3", "Drinker"); 
map.put("4", "Visit Denist"); 
pageContext.setAttribute("map", map); 
%>




<select name="questionid" id="questionids" >
    <c:forEach items="${map}">
        <option value="${items.key}">${items.value}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Comment: I tried this, But no values are showing under the dropdown list

Comment: have you include the above taglib's ?? I have tested above code it is working fine for me... can you give some broad explanation to your problem.

Comment: Yes, It is working now. But I don't need the value to be question text. I need the auto increment numbers for questions like. For first question the value should be 1 and for second the value should be 2 e.t.c

Comment: I am not clear with your suggestion. Can you please explain more on it, Please

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="questionid" id="questionids">
</select>
```

You can build select using javascript dynamically. You may want to use arr value as option value. If you want to use increment you can create a arr and loop them.

```
    var questionids = {"Name", "Age", "Smoker", "Drinker", "Visit Denist"};
//  var valuesArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];       
    $.each(questionids , function(i, e) {
        $('#questionids').append("<option value='"+e+"'>"+e+"</option>");
//      $('#questionids').append("<option value='"+valuesArr[i]+"'>"+e+"</option>");
    });
```